# PiCamera with TensorFlow using parallel programing

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, picamera

I would like to run a continuous stream with the PiCamera on the Raspberry Pi 3 and also do other computations in parallel with this stream. I only have to take from that stream(process) the object that it detected. I will post here the code I have so far. It doesn't enter in the computation() function. It just starts the camera and detects the objects there and stays in that process.

https://pastebin.com/Fbig0t0L

Can you help me with this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code as part of the question.

Comment: This is a general programming question and has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi. You should better ask at https://stackoverflow.com. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.